# Get length of string from scanf

Tags: c, string

I'm getting a word from a user and I need to calculate it's length, but I can't seem to get `strlen()` or `sizeof()` to work for some reason.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
printf("Enter a word: ");
char word;
scanf("%c",&word);
printf("%i",strlen(word));
```

This seems really simple, but I can't print out the length of the string for the life of me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to read a string using only one `char` storage. The only string you can store there is the `null` string (which has length zero) i.e.
`word='\0'`

increase the size of the word buffer. 
Moreover `strlen` expects a `char*` pointer and not a plain `char`.

```
char word[100];
scanf("%s",word);    
printf("%i",strlen(word));
```